# True if arr does not contain target

Tags: java, contains

The goal is to return true if arr does not contain target and false otherwise:

```
public boolean arrayDoesNotContain(int[] arr, int target){
    for (int element : arr) {
        if (element != target) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

I ran this and am getting assertion errors on my tests even though it
fulfills the required task. Any tips or a second pair of eyes to help
me see where this went wrong is appreciated.

Comment: You return the value `true` way too soon, without checking any other value in the array.

Comment: Step through your code. The first non-contained value will return true. That's not what you want. Instead if you find a match return false; then return true at the end

Comment: That makes sense. I figured it was just as simple as telling the program to find the non-contained value and then say true. I was not aware it would just run and stop as soon as we got the first match.

Comment: `return` will always return execution back to the caller as soon as the code hits it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to pinpoint the issue without seeing the tests and the specific assertion errors you're receiving, but one thing to consider is that the current implementation will return true as soon as it finds an element in the array that is not equal to the target, without checking the rest of the elements.

Try this and let me know if that works

```
public boolean arrayDoesNotContain(int[] arr, int target){
    for (int element : arr) {
        if (element == target) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```